# How to save the value in detailtexlabel of tableviewcontroller by entering the value in the textfield of another uiviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have an application where I have 2 controllers, one is a viewcontroller which consists of a textfield and the other is a tableview controller. When I enter any value in the textfield of uiviewcontroller and get back using the navigation bar button item that value must be saved in the detailtextlabel of my previous tableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make property in appDelegate class

```
appDelegateview.h

    NSString *text;

    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *text;


AppDelegateview.h.m 

    @synthesize text

in viewWillDisappear of view.m

  yourAppDelegateClass *obj=(yourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  obj.text=@"your value";

in tableViewController.m


in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

yourAppDelegateClass *obj=(yourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=obj.text;
```

Comment: ishu ya now it is working but there is a problem the textfield value does not retain between tabs

Comment: then after putting textFieldValues in obj.text call this line [obj.text retain];

Comment: i have done this but this not working .When i click on the tabs an come to the same tab their is no value in textfield and so no value in detailtextlabel

Comment: in cellForRow.. of viewController,  use this yourTextField.text=obj.text; obj is object of appDelegate class.

Comment: ishu in my viewController their is no cellforRow method.So where should i put this code

Comment: sorry in viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass a reference of a `NSString` varaiable to the 2nd view controller, change its value there, when your return to first view controller, you get it modified.
2. Use `NSUserDefaults` to set the value in the 2nd view controller. When you come back to the first view controller, read the value in the `viewDidAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty simple. Declare an `NSString` object in your `TableViewController.h` file like this:

`@interface TableViewController.h {`

`NSString *detailTxt; }`

Dont forget to retain and synthesize it.

Now open your other ViewController which contains TextBox. In that, create the object of `TableViewController` like this:

`TableViewController *nextController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];`

Now you have access to your `TableViewController` objects. You can simply call the string you declared in `TableViewController.h` and assign the text in the TextBox.

`nextController.detailTxt = YourTextBoxName.Text;`

Now go back to your TableViewController and assign the text in `detailTxt` string to your `cell.detailTextLabel`. Hope this helps.

Happy Coding!

Comment: i want the value to get saved on my tableviewcontroller when i navigate through the navigation back button of next controller

Comment: May be there is a little mistake in implementing this by you ? You want to detect the click event of `navigationController` ?

Comment: wasim when i navigate from nextcontroller to tableviewcontroller through the navigation barleft back button item the values should get saved on the detailtextlabel

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate method for this.
Send back the value (textfield value) to the first view controller (which contains tableview) through delegate method.

(U need to set the index of the row selected to the secondview controller and u have to send the index along with the value, so that u can update the datasource correctly).

Update the datasource when the value is received.

Reload the tableview in viewWillAppear of the first view controller.

Pre-req : You need to set the value from the datasource to the detailTextLabel.

Comment: which delegate method can u explain me in detail

Comment: You have to write a new delegate (protocol) to send the value back. For more ref abt Protocols, [see here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).